# Clarification on 軍の命令で善悪の区別もつかなくなる

Tags: translation

I'd like to confirm if I'm reading the two following lines correctly - for context, this is a conversation between a soldier and an outlaw who used to be friends and now find themselves at odds.

> A) 君達は軍の命令で善悪の区別もつかなくなってしまったのか！
> *Can’t you even tell right from wrong if the army doesn’t order you to?!*
>
> B) 事情も知らないくせに勝手な事を！
> *You’re ignoring how things are and just go around doing whatever the hell you want!*

(I'm assuming they suppressed the end of B and it's supposed to be "勝手な事を**する**"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A) [君達]{きみたち}は[軍]{ぐん}の[命令]{めいれい}で[善悪]{ぜんあく}の[区別]{くべつ}もつかなくなってしまったのか！
>
> Your TL: "Can’t you even tell right from wrong if the army doesn’t order you to?!"

If it is an attempt at a free translation, yours looks "okay".  It is difficult to comment on a free translation.  One could not, however, tell if you understood the sentence structure from your TL.

This 「で」 means 「によって」.

「A + で + B + になる/くなる」 = "A causes B.", "A brings about B.", etc.  This is why I have to wonder how you chose to use "if" in your translation.

My own (semi-)literal TL would be: "Was it an army order that has made you guys incapable of telling right from wrong?"

Your TL of the second phrase looks just fine as it nicely captures the nuance of the original.  What is left unsaid at the end would be 「しやがって」,「言いやがって」, etc.

Comment: Urgh, that's what I get for writing these in a hurry...you're absolutely right. 

I haven't been translating lines as training for long but I don't think I ever saw 「つかなく」, though　(or at least I can't remember the last time I saw it). 
Can I ask which one of the 「つく」 verbs it's based on to have this 「できなく」 meaning?

Comment: @Brunom1 Does this help? 「区別がつく」⇒「区別がつかない」⇒「区別がつかなくなる」⇒「区別がつかなくなってしまう」⇒「区別がつかなくなってしまった」 where 「〜の区別がつく」 means something like "can tell apart ~" or "can differentiate between ~". As to which つく this is, I guess it might be ５ア in the [大辞林 entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F-330713).

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie Yes, that's perfect.

Thank you both!

Comment: @Brunom1 Regarding sentence B: "ignoring [the situation]" means something completely different from "being ignorant of [the situation]". While 知らない can be used to mean either of these, I believe the latter makes a lot more sense given your context.

Comment: @Will
Hmm, I did think of that but I went with this because it implies the outlaw is purposely ignoring what's going on around him (which he is, the outlaw states that he wants nothing to do with the army and this war they're fighting)